# GemFire put and get data in my local system

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, cloud-foundry

I am learning GemFire and as part of that, I downloaded the package and started GemFire locator and server through GFSH

Now I am trying to test it by writing a sample Java code which will connect to GemFire and put and get the data

But I don't know how to do it. Also all the materials in internet shows only sample code to start the cache and listen to cache

No material available to PUT / GET data. Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-gemfire-examples and specifically https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-gemfire-examples/tree/master/basic/replicated-cs is a good starting point.